# Set custom model to CvSVM in OpenCv

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, svm

I'm using CvSVM from OpenCV for a regression task. For reasons related to legacy code, currently I have to train the model using Matlab, but then I'd like to load it into CvSVM and perform prediction in a C++ code with OpenCV due to application constraints. I did not find a way in the OpenCV documentation to load a saved model, did I miss something? Or is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a load function

```
CvSVM *SVM = new CvSVM;
SVM->load("SVM.xml");
```

Comment: just be aware, that this is for models previously trained and saved from opencv's *own* svm. you can't load arbitrary xml here (and i doubt, tht the matlab output will fit this)